# How to convert data in a specific period of time to nan?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
          CODE      DATE      STATION   TMAX_x    SECTOR
0       472606FA 2001-01-05   AYABACA     NaN         CN
         ...        ...       ...     ...        ...
.       472606FA 2017-01-01   AYABACA    18.0         CN
.       472606FA 2017-01-02   AYABACA    18.7         CN
.       472606FA 2017-01-03   AYABACA    19.6         CN
.       472606FA 2017-01-04   AYABACA     NaN         CN
.       472606FA 2017-01-05   AYABACA     NaN         CN
         ...        ...       ...     ...        ...
.       472606FA 2017-04-26   AYABACA    18.0         CN
.       472606FA 2017-04-27   AYABACA    18.7         CN
.       472606FA 2017-04-28   AYABACA    19.6         CN
.       472606FA 2017-04-29   AYABACA     NaN         CN
.       472606FA 2017-04-30   AYABACA     NaN         CN
         ...        ...       ...     ...        ...
248220  47E2A75C 2017-04-26  VILACOTA    10.0         SI
248221  47E2A75C 2017-04-27  VILACOTA    11.5         SI
248222  47E2A75C 2017-04-28  VILACOTA    10.1         SI
248223  47E2A75C 2017-04-29  VILACOTA    12.5         SI
248224  47E2A75C 2017-04-30  VILACOTA     NaN         SI

[248225 rows x 5 columns]
```

I want to convert `TMAX_x` data to NaN only from 2017-01-01 to 2017-04-30 in every `STATION` with `SECTOR` equal to CN and SI.

PD: There are 49 `STATION` names and some stations in `SECTOR` column have values different to CN and SI so i think it is important to groupby first by `STATION`.

So i tried this code:

```
df['YEAR_MONTH'] = df.DATE.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
df.loc[df['SECTOR'] == 'CN', '1ST PERIOD TO REMOVE'] = '2017-01'
df.loc[df['SECTOR'] == 'SI', '1ST PERIOD TO REMOVE'] = '2017-01'

df.loc[df['SECTOR'] == 'CN', '2COND PERIOD TO REMOVE'] = '2017-04'
df.loc[df['SECTOR'] == 'SI', '2COND PERIOD TO REMOVE'] = '2017-04'

df['TMAX_x'] = df['TMAX_x'].mask(df['YEAR_MONTH'].ge(df['1ST PERIOD TO REMOVE']) 
                         & df['YEAR_MONTH'].le(df['2COND PERIOD TO REMOVE']))
```

But ge and le just admit numbers not string so i don't know how to do this.

Would you mind to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume 'DATE' is a datetime64:

```
# Convert 'DATE' to datetime64 if it's not already done before
# df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

df.loc[df['SECTOR'].isin(['CN', 'SI'])
       & df['DATE'].between('2017-01-01', '2017-04-30'), 'TMAX_x'] = np.NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

convert `DATE` column and start and stop values to pandas datetime, then create the required mask, you can use `.isin` to check for multiple values, then finally use the mask alongwith `.loc` accessor to modify the value.

```py
#convert to pandas date time
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], yearfirst=True)
start = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01', yearfirst=True)
stop = pd.to_datetime('2017-04-30', yearfirst=True)

#create the mask and use it alongwith .loc to modify
mask = (df['SECTOR'].isin(['CN',  'SI']))&(df['DATE'].ge(start))&(df['DATE'].le(stop))
df.loc[mask, 'TMAX_x'] = np.nan
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
        CODE       DATE   STATION TMAX_x SECTOR
0   472606FA 2001-01-05   AYABACA    NaN     CN
2   472606FA 2017-01-01   AYABACA    NaN     CN
3   472606FA 2017-01-02   AYABACA    NaN     CN
4   472606FA 2017-01-03   AYABACA    NaN     CN
5   472606FA 2017-01-04   AYABACA    NaN     CN
6   472606FA 2017-01-05   AYABACA    NaN     CN
8   472606FA 2017-04-26   AYABACA    NaN     CN
9   472606FA 2017-04-27   AYABACA    NaN     CN
10  472606FA 2017-04-28   AYABACA    NaN     CN
11  472606FA 2017-04-29   AYABACA    NaN     CN
12  472606FA 2017-04-30   AYABACA    NaN     CN
14  47E2A75C 2017-04-26  VILACOTA    NaN     SI
15  47E2A75C 2017-04-27  VILACOTA    NaN     SI
16  47E2A75C 2017-04-28  VILACOTA    NaN     SI
17  47E2A75C 2017-04-29  VILACOTA    NaN     SI
18  47E2A75C 2017-04-30  VILACOTA    NaN     SI
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# Example data including dates as datetime
dates = pd.date_range(start="01.01.2017",end="31.12.2018")
n = len(dates)

data = {"Sector":np.random.choice(["CN", "SI", "Other"], n), 
        "Station":np.random.choice(["AYABACA", "VILACOTA","OTHER"], n), 
        "TMAX_x":np.random.choice([1,2,3,4], n), 
        "Date": dates}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Filter rows based on conditions

df.loc[df["Date"].between("01.01.2017", "30.04.2017") 
       & ((df["Sector"] == "CN") | (df["Sector"] == "SI")), "TMAX_x"] = np.nan
```